# Calculate data in the same cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure how to do this; I was hoping someone could help me out here.

I would like for a cell to automatically update a mathematical equation after I enter a number.

I would like to do this because each transaction I have costs 10 cents, plus 2% fee for credit cards.

So for example, 
 transactions(D15)=21 amount(E15)=108

I would like the results cell to update with the transactions and amounts cells.

In this case, I would use the following formula:

(D15*0.10)-(E15-2%) = 103.78.

So E15 will automatically update with 103.78.

I currently need to copy and paste, and I would like for it to update automaticly.

Anyone? This would be great. Thanks a lot. I'm not sure if this would require a Macro or if I can insert it as a cell function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you will need to add macros to your sheet (*Alt+F11 and double click your Sheet Name in Microsoft Excel Objects*), and then something like this will solve your problem:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target = [E15] Then    'enters when cell E15 is modified
    Dim transactions
    transactions = [D15]

    Dim amount
    amount = [E15]

    Application.EnableEvents = False  'very important!
    Target.Value = amount - transactions * 0.1 - amount * (0.02)
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    [E15].Activate     'select the same cell again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Be careful with `Application.EnableEvents=False` this deactivates the events so the formula will not get calculated again and again and again...

Excel  will call `Worksheet_Change` every time you change the value of any cell in the current sheet.

Comment: oh yep it is very stupid, I know, I was just enjoying myself (remembering VBA) and _earning some points_. Thanks!

Comment: well, i hope its not stupid, the reason why is so i can print the statement to my client so they dont need to see 19 pages worth of transactions, if they do, they will just ask me for them and we have no problem printing them out. this is only to really simplify the accounting tables. I appreciate your help, because of it being Macro i would have no idea where to start. i will give this a shot this afternoon. thanks allot!